# Unable to load and display data from parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, label

```
    var findPublisher:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    findPublisher.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: quote.objectForKey("publisher")!)
    findPublisher.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFUser] {
                for object in objects {
                    //println(object.objectId)
                    let user:PFuser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser
                    cell.publisherLabel.text = user.username
                }

            }
        }
    // Configure the cell...
    }
```

The code here is supposed to query for the `objectId` and display the username instead of the label. I am getting an error that says use of undeclared type of 'PFUser'... I used "println" right after the `error == nil` statement and it logs correctly so the error definitely occurs after there.

Comment: what are trying to query

Comment: i am trying to query the object id so then i can display the username that the objectId represents

Comment: you are trying to query all the username into a UITableview right

Comment: i am trying to query all the usernames into the UITableview

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a TableViewController, you don't need to create an Outlet of the tableview. So you need to query all the objects from the _User class into an array. So it is up to you to know where you want to place this code either in the ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear.

```
 var arrayOFUser :NSMutableArray = []

    var findPublisher:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"_User")
    findPublisher.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    var getusername = object["username"] as! String
                    self.arrayOFUser.addObject(getusername)
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

// return the count of user into the each cell in the tableview

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.arrayOFUser.count
}

    then you go into the ** cellForRowAtIndexPath** method

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  var cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellSubtitle", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

      let name = self.arrayOFUser[indexPath.row] as! String
        cell.textlabel?.text = name 
            return cell
        }
```

QuickNote "CellSubtitle" is the name of the cell in the tableview so go into the storyboard in change it.

Comment: I am getting the errors that my table view controller class does not have the members arrayofUser and tablview